# Retrieve specific Record from an array after findOneAndUpdate Mongoose 5.x

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a document like below:

```
{
  _id: '1'
  persons: [
    {
      userId: 'user1',
      changed: false
    },
    {
      userId: 'user2',
      changed: false
    },
  ]
}
```

I can simply do like below to update a specific record inside `persons`:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: '1',
    'persons.userId': 'user1'
  },
  {
    $set: { persons.$.changed: true }
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

But the returned `document` will contain every element from `persons` array, is there any way so that I can get the specific array elements matching the condition `'persons.userId': 'user1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#projection) as one of the parameters of `findAndModify`, try:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: "1",
        "persons.userId": "user1"
    },
    {
        $set: { "persons.$.changed": true }
    },
    { 
        new: true,
        projection: {
            persons: {
                $elemMatch: { userId: "user1" }
            }
        } 
    }
)
```